# Display Multiple Values of Same Key

Tags: custom-field

I am going to put multiple value on custom field using same key (my key is link). So the value will be value A and value B

And heres my custom field code for single value:

```
<a href="<?php $key="link"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?>" target="_blank">Images Source</a>
```

So the question is ,how to display multiple value one? as you can see I have my code for single value already above.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
// get an array of multiple values
$post_meta_array = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'link'); // do not use 'true' as the third argument
// echo the link for each value 
foreach ($post_meta_array as $post_meta) {
    echo '<a href="' . $post_meta . '" target="_blank">Images Source</a>';
}
```